# How can you use a flatlist to render components in react native

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist, flatlist

I am currently creating an onboarding screen which is just a few components navigating linear to the next component on a button click.
However I’ve seen I could use a flatlist to style this better. Is it possible to pass components to a flatlist as the data prop?

```
     import React from 'react';
    import { SafeAreaView, View, FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
   import DateOfBirth, Name, ProfilePicture from ‘./components’
    
    const DATA = [
      DateOfBirth, Name, ProfilePicture
    ];
   

 return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
          <FlatList
            data={DATA}
          />
        </SafeAreaView>
      );
    }
```

Would this be possible for example? I know there is a renderedItems prop which seems to do something similar but seems to match the data to the item which isn’t what I really want. Is there anyway better?
Or if there is any better libraries for onboarding options in react native that would be great. Most of what I see is similar to a flatlist and adds just an array with text rather than inputs etc

Answer (score 3):

```
const DATA = [
 <MyComponent />,
 <MyOtherComponent />,
 <Etc />,
 <Etc />,
]

 const ListItem = ({ item }) => {
   return <View> {item} </View>
  }

<View>
  <FlatList
    data={DATA}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => String(index)}
    renderItem={ListItem}
  />
</View>
```

Comment: thank you , exactly what i needed ,  and i think that's exactly what the original post asked for

Answer (score 2):

```js
import React from 'react';
import {View,Text,StyleSheet,FlatList} from 'react-native';
const Demo = () => {
  let ary = [
  {
     id:1,
     name:'jahnavi',
  },
   {
     id:2,
     name:'yash',
  },
   {
     id:3,
     name:'aniket',
  }],
  


  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
       keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        data={ary}
        renderItem={({item}) => (<Item title={item.name}/>
        );
  }
       
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
export default Demo;
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to set the `renderItem` prop. Style the `<Item />` component to meet your requirement.

```
const App = () => {
  const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <Item title={item.title} />
  );

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={DATA}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't understand why you're trying to do with your components.

To use Flatlist, you need to pass data and THEN use your components.

Learn more here https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist

Example

```
import React from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, View, FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import DateOfBirth, Name, ProfilePicture from ‘./components’
    
const DATA = [
    {
        name: "Jhon Doe",
        dateOfBirth: "01/01/1980",
        profilePicture: "https://url.com/profile.jpg"
    },
    {
        name: "Jane Doe",
        dateOfBirth: "02/01/1980",
        profilePicture: "https://url.com/profile2.jpg"
    }
];

const App = () => {
    function renderClient ({client}){
        return(
            <View key={client.index}>
                <Name name={client.item.name} />
            </View>
        )
    }

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
            <FlatList
                data={DATA}
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                renderItem={renderClient}
            />
        </SafeAreaView>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: So if my components are just inputs say DateOfBirth is just a date picker. I could pass the input as a prop to the DateOfBirth component and then pass that up to the flatlist component data? I’m fairly new to react native, I’ve seen options to say create a horizontal scroll view and just add the components that way. Because my end goal would be once I have all the data from the components to then post that to an api on the last page with a button

Comment: I think you need to learn more about react before going further. There are many free online courses